# Download multiple(Paralllel) files(.mp4) with progressbar and save it to gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I have to download multiple .mp4 videos and show progressBar for each. I have to display these progress in a tableView. I know how to download a single video and know how to save it to gallery using ...

Currently using this code..

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  NSLog(@"Downloading Started");

  NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://original.mp4";

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];

 NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

 if ( urlData )
 {

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

   NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"thefile.mp4"];

//saving is done on main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

          NSLog(@"File Saved !");
});
}

});
```

**First Approach**

1. First of all how can i show progress while downloading using above
   code.
2. Then i also don't know where is it downloading. I want to know the
   path where above code save .mp4 video and also want to modify(save
   it in gallery).
3. I also want to show download progress for each video.

**Second Approach**

I think i have to use NSOperationQueue too run the downloads asynchronously, allow a certain number to be done in parallel,etc . but don't know how to implement it with progress ..

Comment: Do you need parallel download or serial downloads?

Comment: I need parallel download .

Answer (score 0):

I created something that had to download multiple tasks and it shows the progress of each on too: http://github.com/ManavGabhawala/CAEN-Lecture-Scraper (this is for the mac)
Basically what you need to do is create a custom UITableViewCell class which has the progress bar inside of it and an IBOutlet to the bar. Then make the class of the cell conform to NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate to get the progress as it comes in. Further, I used a semaphore to ensure only 3 downloads happened simultaneously. Here's the class for your convenience:

```
let downloadsAllowed = dispatch_semaphore_create(3)
class ProgressCellView: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!
    var downloadURL : NSURL!
    var saveToPath: NSURL!

    func setup(downloadURL: NSURL, saveToPath: NSURL)
    {
        self.downloadURL = downloadURL
        self.saveToPath = saveToPath
        statusLabel.text = "Waiting To Queue"
        // Optionally call begin download here if you don't want to wait after queueing all the cells.
    }

    func beginDownload()
    {
        statusLabel.text = "Queued"
        let session =
        NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue())
        let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(downloadURL)!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(downloadsAllowed, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.statusLabel.text = "Downloading"
            })
            task.resume()
        })
    }
}
extension ProgressCellView : NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate
{
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64)
    {
        progressBar.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite), animated: true)
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL)
    {
        // TODO: Write file downloaded.
        // Copy file from `location` to `saveToPath` and handle errors as necessary.
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(downloadsAllowed)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Downloaded"
        })
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?)
    {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        // TODO: Do error handling.
    }
}
```

Change the creation of semaphore value to whatever you want it to be (the number of concurrent downloads allowed). Also note that you must call setup on the cell with the downloadURL and saveToPath after instantiating it. If you want to immediately queue and download the videos call `beginDownload()` inside of `setup()`. Otherwise, call it on each and every cell whenever you want to start downloading all the videos.